# Many to many objects duplicated

Tags: django

I am running a process to migrate a lot of call data. I have a model representing a phone line, and another model representing a caller. A phone line can have more than one caller, and a caller can phone more than one phone line. So a many to many relation is needed.

For 442/444 of the phone lines, the code below works and the caller is created and linked to a phone line or added to the relation.

However, in 2 cases duplicates are being created.  That is, the phone line will store two caller instances with the same number.

How can I prevent this?

---

```
class Caller(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phoneline = models.ManyToManyField(
        PhoneLine,
        related_name="callers"
    )

class PhoneLine(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, 
        default=""
    )
```

---

```
try:
    caller = Caller.objects.get(number=number)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    caller = Caller.objects.create(number=number)
    caller.save()
if not caller.phoneline.filter(pk=phoneline.pk).exists():
    caller.phoneline.add(phoneline)
```

Comment: Please, show the code for your models declaration.

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto Sorry, added

Comment: @HPJM does it happen consistently, every time a Caller is added with one of these two phone lines, there are multiples?   What is the database, and is what are the phone line names?  If you query them from a database client, do you see the rows duplicated?

Comment: @LevinMagruder Yes, every time a new Caller is added. DB is MySQL. What do you mean by phone line names? If make queries, I can see the duplicated callers. They have unique ids but the same number.

Comment: If your query for `caller.phoneline` compares with `phoneline.pk`, means that you already have a `phoneline` object. Can you show the code where you get `phoneline` instance?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
caller, created = Caller.objects.get_or_create(number=number)
caller.phoneline.add(phoneline)
```

`get_or_create` method [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Django many to many field automatically check duplicate and if exists, not create.

Comment: That's a nice shortcut but the problem still persists